# Cannot use Jacoco in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, jacoco

In my Java app, in order to generate coverage reports for my Unit Tests, I have tried several approaches to setup Jacoco as in [Run with coverage](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html) or [this](https://gist.github.com/topriddy/1168ab4788531796a2e8988b85bfb09d) page. However, I cannot generate coverage reports as expected and I think I need some steps describing the setup of Jacoco on IntelliJ. So, does anybody else have experience for setup and run it via command line as shown below:

```
mvn --global-settings ../settings.xml 
    -Dtest="/com/mycompany/core/service/impl/unit/ProductServiceImplTest.java" test
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*I cannot generate coverage reports as expected*" - what does this exactly mean? what is your expectation? what you get?

Comment: First, I need to install Jacoco in IntelliJ IDEA and generate coverage reports via command line.

Comment: have you tried changing "test" to "verify" on the command line?

Comment: @harry we can't see whether you're using maven plugin, which exact version/plugin it is, how you configure it.. please include more information, as it's impossible to answer "*it's not working as expected*" question, without having, at least, some details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helps. When I was looking for a solution, I found that I run first clean and then test tasks on Maven toolbar. Then the coverage reports are generated. **However**, I need to generate coverage reports for a specific package or class. So, how can I manage this?